# Safari says "can't open page" but JSON return is normal

Tags: arduino, wifi, esp8266

My homebrew Wi-Fi temperature sensor works when connected to one of my access points, but with another one I get "Safari can't open the page because the server unexpectedly dropped the connection." Yet looking at the device log (in Arduino) it appears to respond correctly with a very short JSON record:

```
new client
Request: GET /temperature/F HTTP/1.1
Response: {"TempF":65.30}

Client disconnected
```

Also, accessing the device with `curl http://xx.yy.zz.ww/temperature/F` produces the desired JSON response.

I don't know where to start looking for the problem (tried it with Chrome and got the same result).

I have Safari's "Develop" menu enabled. I've been through all the router settings and don't see anything that could cause this.

I'm using the Arduino ESP8266 library.

Comment: Is this response don't have any valid HTTP Headers? I don't know whether this library contains the part of automatically fill in the necessary HTTP Headers like "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" (the HTTP status code), but for my other project, sometimes this reason sucks.

Comment: And, the `request` are needed to build a HTTP request header, I guess the `response` needs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an Arduino board, and not used that library, however I think this can solve your issue.

As for my search of the [Arduino ESP8266 library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino), it is just an TCP and UDP library, not an HTTP library. So you have to implement all the HTTP headers by yourself, which can also be indicated by `Request` field in your question. Then I think if filling the `Response` with a valid HTTP response format may solve this issue, for example

```
Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 15\r\n\r\n{"TempF":65.30}
```

Comment: Once I implemented both the Content-Type and Content-Length headers, it now works with all browsers. Unlike Safari, Firefox has a very nice feature that, for a JSON response, lets you see the decoded data, the raw data (optionally prettyprinted), or the headers. Nice!